# How can I get all affected row ids in mysql group by sentence?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am doing a selection using GROUP BY, so I get a lot of different rows. What I need is to UPDATE the status field of each row affected by the SELECT query, but it is grouped... so I don't know all the ids, just the MAX(id).

This is the select query:

```
    SELECT d.*, n.* FROM
    (SELECT MAX(id) as id, MAX(datetime) as datetime, COUNT(DISTINCT content) as total FROM user_notifications 
    WHERE id_user
    GROUP BY id_ref, type
    ORDER BY datetime DESC) d
    JOIN user_notifications n USING (id)
```

Edit:

Simple example, this is the table

```
id  user    content status
1   1       aaa     0
2   1       aaa     0
3   1       bbb     0
4   2       aaa     0
5   3       bbb     0
```

this is the query

```
select max(id), user, content from table where user=1 group by content
```

this is the result

```
id  user    content
2   1       aaa
3   1       bbb
```

in this query in fact sql internally select all user=1 (id= 1, 2, 3) and then the query is grouped, showing just two rows.

So, I want to update all ids involved in the query (id= 1 , 2 and 3)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why are you joining with `user_notifications`, but not selecting anything from that?

Comment: What do you mean by "each row afffected by the sentence"? The query uses all the rows in the table, since there's no `WHERE` clause to restrict it.

Comment: BTW, it's called a query, not a sentence.

Comment: thank you @Barmar for the correction, sorry for my english

Comment: can you create a very small example with http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @EchoMike444 I edited the post with an example

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, you need the result exact to this query:

```
select id from `table` where user = 1;
```

But by using the query you provided which groups record by content

```
select max(id), user, content from `table` where user = 1 group by content
```

So, in such case you can join same table with derived table:

```
select id from `table` as t
join (select max(id), user, content from `table` where user = 1 group by content) as dt 
on dt.content = t.content and dt.user = t.user;
```

This query is now equivalent to first straight forward query.